# Devise users - show only the false boolean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, boolean, admin

I would like to show in my index the users that are waiting to be approved (false = unnaproved). I followed the steps in this link(controllers and views):

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Require-admin-to-activate-account-before-sign_in

I have tried many ways, but nothing seems to work. My code is:

**controller:**

```
def index
if params[:approved] == "false"
    @users = User.find_by_approved(false)
else
   @users = User.all
end
```

end

**View index**

```
<% @users.each do |users| %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= users.name%></td>
                <td><%= users.email %></td>
                <td><%= users.approved %></td>
                <td><%= link_to "Aprobar", desaprobado_path(users) %></td>
                </tr>
            <%end%>
```

The index show me all the users (false and true), not only the false ones.
Any idea? thanks! greetings from Chile and excuse my english.

Comment: Add `?approved=true` to the url and try again.

Comment: Thanks for reply. The result is the same, the index show me all the users.

Comment: Sorry, I meant ?approved=false

Comment: NoMethodError in Desaprobados#index -> undefined method `each' for #<User in <% @users.each do |users| %>.

Comment: Change `@users = User.find_by_approved(false)` to `@users = User.where(approved: false)`

Comment: yes! that fix the issue. I have to add  "?approved=false" and change for "@users = User.find_by_approved(false) to @users = User.where(approved: false)". I have to learn a lot. Bye and thanks to all.